# IAP в юнити для iOS

Tags: unity3d, in-app-purchases

Прошу прошение но я в первые пытаюсь создать покупки, может есть добрый человек обьяснит как это делается мне нужно создать Consumable покупки, вроде есть на офф юнити но не знаю как настройти ((. пугает мысль что делается на Юнитй под IOS там ведь 2 разных языка...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Интеграция IAP модуля в Unity не является сложным процессом, вы можете посмотреть подробный гайд [здесь](https://unity3d.com/ru/learn/tutorials/topics/ads-analytics/integrating-unity-iap-your-game), инструкция на английском с официального сайта, но все расписано довольно просто и по шагам.

Что касается iOS покупок - это тоже не должно вас беспокоить. Да, действительно, на данный момент iOS приложения можно разрабатывать сразу на двух языках (Swift и Objective-C). Тем не менее, сами покупки в нативных iOS приложениях осуществляются с помощью стандартного framework под названием StoreKit, информацию о котором можно посмотреть [здесь](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit). Однако, обя языка совместимы между собой. Под этим я подразумеваю, что у разработчиков есть возможность написать приложения на любом из этих языков, но также можно совмещать их использование внутри одного приложения. Сам по себе Swift основан на Objective-C, также есть возможность пользоваться классами на Swift из Objective-C кода и наоборот. Framework StoreKit есть для каждого из них. Соответственно работу с этим framework Unity берет на себя, и вам совсем не нужно об этом беспокоиться.

Сам Unity для работы с нативными функциями iOS (например при использовании нативных плагинов) использует Objective-C (а точнее его версию, которая некогда носила название Objective-C++ - об этом немного информации [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3684112/what-is-objective-c)). Сам движок Unity написан с использованием C++, а при разработке iOS приложений можно использовать вставки как чистого C, так и С++ кода, поэтому проблем с интеграцией нативного кода у Unity не возникает.

Что касается IAP со стороны iOS, вам также потребуется создать необходимые покупки на itunesconnect.apple.com . На эту тему у Apple также написан подробный [гайд](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnectInAppPurchase_Guide/Chapters/CreatingInAppPurchaseProducts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013727-CH3-SW1). Общую информацию о покупках можно посмотреть [здесь](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnectInAppPurchase_Guide/Chapters/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013727)

Comment: Большое спасибо! сделал и протестил покупки